# OpenCL barriers: how to make a barrier for all kernels?

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenCL kernel, that runs in global configuration [1024x1024] and does not work with workgroups (it is a simple color-splitting kernel).

I placed there a `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)` synchronization, in order to wait while all the threads from [1024x1024] configuration reach it. But alas, it seems like it does not work.

Cannot you tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

```
typedef float dtype;

// Splits color channels in-place
__kernel void nhwc_to_nchw(__global dtype* pic_data, __global dtype* buffer,
                           const int n_pics, const int n_chans)
{
  size_t pic_h = get_global_size(0);
  size_t pic_w = get_global_size(1);

  size_t pic_y = get_global_id(0);
  size_t pic_x = get_global_id(1);

  size_t nhwc_index;
  size_t nchw_index;
  size_t pic_index;

//  printf("%i %i %zu %zu\n", n_pics, n_chans, pic_h, pic_w);

  for(int n = 0; n < n_pics; n++) {
    // Writting the splitted channels from one pic to buffer
    pic_index = n * n_chans * pic_w * pic_h;
    for(int chan = 0; chan < n_chans; chan++) {
      nhwc_index = pic_y * pic_w * n_chans + pic_x * n_chans + chan;
      nchw_index = chan * pic_h * pic_w + pic_y * pic_w + pic_x;
//      printf("%f\n", pic_data[pic_index + nhwc_index]);
      buffer[nchw_index] = pic_data[pic_index + nhwc_index];
    }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    //Reading splitted channels from buffer and placing them to source pic
    for(int chan = 0; chan < n_chans; chan++) {
      nchw_index = chan * pic_h * pic_w + pic_y * pic_w + pic_x;
      pic_data[pic_index + nchw_index] = buffer[nchw_index];
    }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
  }

}
```

Comment: What does n_pics typically equal? min/max?

Comment: About 100 or 200 pics.

Answer (score 3):

**CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE:**

- Syncs the GLOBAL read/writes within a WORKGROUP.

**CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE:**

- Syncs the LOCAL read/writes within a WORKGROUP.

What you really want, is to sync the GLOBAL read/writes within a kernel. And that is not possible in OpenCL (and neither in any GPU programming language). If your kernel would fit in a single workgroup then it would be fine, but I really doubt that 1M WI can fit in a single group.

**The most proper and portable approach is to split the kernel in two kernels if you need that behavior.**

Comment: Aditional bonus: Seeing what you are trying to achieve, the best approach is to create an out_buffer, and copy input to output directly in one single step. Writing to an intermediate global buffer is VERY slow, and creates you the problem of overlapping between threads that led to the sync problem. That way you can cut off the problem from the beggining.